# What special chars can be used in template name?

Tags: meteor

Can I or is it safe to use these names?

```
<template name="a-b">
<template name="a.b">
<template name="a_b">
<template name="a/b">
<template name="a:b">
```

What special chars can be used in template name?

Comment: If I remember correctly, JavaScript accepts any Unicode character as a variable name (or an object field), so it's safe in that regard. However I don't know if Meteor will accept them internally...